# Where Does Ubuntu Execute Hdparm.conf Settings

Tags: ubuntu, hdparm

I'm looking for some info about the hdparm.conf file in Ubuntu (Jaunty). I have added some settings in there and would like to "run" them.

1. How can I execute the hdparm.conf file from the command line?
2. What start-up script in Ubuntu restores the hdparm.conf settings during boot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These days most of the hdparm settings seem to be done by udev see /lib/udev/rules.d/85-hdparm.rules.  That rule calls this script **/lib/udev/hdparm** which seems to read the hdparm.conf.